# why does Software update says 18.10 is now available when it's still May of 2018?

Tags: updates, security, 18.04

I ran `sudo update-manager -d` and it told me that it failed to download repository information as follows,

[image: Failed to download repository information screenshot]

After clicking OK and proceeding got the following, which is so weird.

[image: Ubuntu 18.10 update in May, 2018 screenshot]

This is so funny and weird. I couldn't think of an explanation why this would happen. I am also wondering if my PCs security is compromised.

Comment: No I have not enabled pre-release updates. The answer by Organic Marble explains the situation. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `-d` that you supplied on the command caused this result.

From the man page for `update-manager`

```
 -d, --devel-release
              If  using  the latest supported release, upgrade to the develop‐
              ment release
```

Leave off the `-d` and you won't get the development version (18.10 at this writing).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This explains it all. I should've checked the man page first.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an indicator that your system has been compromised.

18.10 is available as a Development release. You can download it and run it but it is not supported. You must expect errors, and those errors may even damage your data. Use it only if you intend to contribute to it through either submitting detailed bug reports or by accepting work assignments to fix bugs and develop features.

This is standard procedure. After the release of a release, the next release is put into Development.

18.10 is scheduled as a supported release in October of 2018.

Comment: Thank you! I've known about dev releases/updates and their stability. But did not know that those updates are also rolled out as the next stable release version number.